# How can I filter the path aliases by node id?

Tags: forms, path-aliases, 9

On this page `admin/config/search/path`, we can only filter the results by URL alias.

I want to filter the results by node id as well?

How can I do that?

It is not possible with form alter. As the original form submit is redirecting to the `entity.path_alias.collection` route with the url alias filter only.

Is there any way, I can filter them by node id?

Comment: Path aliases aren't necessarily for nodes. That's why that page doesn't allow to filter by node ID. If it were doing that, it should also filter by taxonomy term, or other entity IDs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The **URL alias** page it's not a view so, there is no way to add new filter via UI, but you can add a new filter programmatically:
Here is an article explaining how to do so [DRUPAL 8 ADD ANOTHER FILTER TO URL ALIASES PAGE](https://www.berramou.com/blog/drupal-8-add-another-filter-url-aliases-page)
you need to adjust a little bit the code provided in the article it's for path field and you need nid field !